# How do I add a FlatPageAdmin?

Tags: django

**Welcome friends**

I need your help.

I would like to use FlatPageAdmin. Like in the example below.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'sites')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('registration_required', 'template_name'),
        }),
    )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

[image]

It may of course be very simple, but I don't know, how to do this.

**this my admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import Order
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email']
    list_filter = ['name']

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

I'm trying. But whatever I do I always get:

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Although I add

```
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```

How to solve a problem ?

I would appreciate your help

UPDATE

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'crispy_forms',
    'order',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Friends - works

I don't know if it's the best way, but only I changed this line:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import Order
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('xxx', 'xxx', 'email')}),
        (_('Advanced options'), {
            'classes': ('collapse', ),
            'fields': (
                'xxx',
            ),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx',
                    'xxx',
                    'xx', 'xx', xx]
    list_filter = ['x', 'x', 'x']

admin.site.register(Order, FlatPageAdmin)
```

This solved my problem and hope this will help you in future.